# Context Manger in Robotframework Test Library

Tags: python, robotframework, contextmanager

I would like to embed a [test library](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-libraries) into robotframework that itself is using [a context manager library](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html#implementing-a-context-manager-as-a-class) to provide test data.

I was wondering that there is no 'ready to go' functionality or API for this (, am I right?). I like to avoid to make a `setup` and a `teardown` keyword [3](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-setup-and-teardown), since e.g. on error case the teardown keyword could be skipped -- and *not worse to mention it is boiler code*.

Nicer in my eyes would be the auto deconstruction on test (suite) end. Imagine a plenty of test suites are using this library. It would make sense to import library at robot file or as ListenerInterface via cli, see idea below.

I was think about basing on the [Listener Interface](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface) that embeds the context manager `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods onto `start_suite`/`end_suite` api-calls. (For the first time *on test suite setup/teardown*, but it might make sense to extended this technique for test or keyword scale as well.)

1. **Am I right, that there is API idea on embeding [a context manager library](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html#implementing-a-context-manager-as-a-class) libraries, yet (glueing into robots `setup`/`teardown` model)? (I only the the chance to define keywords explicite.)**
2. **Are there some (other) ideas or techniques to embed context manager libs into test libraries?** (Might be question 1 related and maybe some point for an github issue.)

This idea will work (to whom that might faced to the same issue):

```py
from typing import ContextManager
from robot.running.model import TestSuite as TestSuiteModel
from robot.result.model import TestSuite as TestSuiteResult


@library(scope='Test Suite', doc_format='reST')
class MyResourceLib:
    '''
    User Test Library making use of context manager: `MyDBContextManger`
    '''
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 3

    class __init__(self, some_resource: Optional[MyDBContextManger] = None):
        self.ROBOT_LIBRARY_LISTENER = self
        if not some_resource:
            self.some_resource = MyDBContextManger()
        else:
            self.some_resource = some_resource

    def start_suite(self, data: TestSuiteModel, result: TestSuiteResult) -> None:
        '''
        Robot Library Listener interface v3.
        '''
        assert self.some_resource
        self.some_resource.__enter__()

    def end_suite(self, data: TestSuiteModel, result: TestSuiteResult) -> None:
        '''
        Robot Library Listener interface v3.
        '''
        assert self.some_resource
        self.some_resource.__exit__(None, None, None)
```